# How to simulate OnMouseMove event on TMenuItem?

Tags: delphi, menu, c++builder, menuitem

When mouse cursor is over some menu item (TMainMenu) then the item is highlighted. I would like to add a text inside my status bar describing the menu item but I have no OnMouseMove or any similiar event for TMenuItem to do this. How to achive this?

I'm using C++ Builder XE6.
Thanks!

Comment: Read the [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle//en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem.Hint)

Comment: Thanks! This should be it. I still would like to see if some kind of event is possible.. Edit: Wil try to investigate TApplication.OnHint event.

Comment: See [TStatusBar.AutoHint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TStatusBar.AutoHint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VCL can handle this automatically for you.

Assign your desired text to the [`TMenuItem.Hint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem.Hint) property:

> Specifies the text string that can appear when the user moves the mouse pointer over a menu item.
>
> Set Hint to a string that provides more information about the meaning of the menu item than the Caption. **The hint text appears in the Status Bar when the user pauses with the mouse over the menu item** if Help Hints are enabled (that is, if the Form's and the Application's ShowHint properties are True). It is also available for the code in the application's OnHint event handler.

And then set the [`TStatusBar.AutoHint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TStatusBar.AutoHint) property to true.

> Specifies whether the status bar's text is set automatically to the current hint.
>
> Use AutoHint to specify whether the status bar's text is set automatically to the current hint. **When AutoHint is True, the status bar automatically responds to hint actions by displaying the long version of the hint's text in the first panel**.

Any changes to the [`TApplication.Hint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Hint) property, such as when the mouse moves over a UI control or menu item, will propagate to the `TStatusBar` automatically.

Comment: Yes. I just investigated this myself and used it. Thanks!